# what is difference between using $ or `(tilt) while calling a function and normally calling the function with its name

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I am a beginner for shell scripting and stuck in a very strange problem.
I have a shell script called as

```
functions.sh
```

which contains several functions that can be called from other shell scripts. which contains two functions like this:

```
function setInputTableForCurrentFlow(){
if [[ $1 == *"."* ]] && [[ $2 != "" ]];
then
        if [ "$SERVER_NOT_RUNNING_VAR" != "$SERVER_NOT_RUNNING" ] && [ "$SESSION_ID" != "" ];
        then
                CURRENT_DB=$(echo $1 | cut -d'.' -f1);
                CURRENT_TABLE=$(echo $1 | cut -d'.' -f2);
                PARTITION_CONTAINS_EQUAL_SIGN=$2;
                server_response=$(  \
                        curl  \
                        -s    \
                        -X POST \
                        --cookie "JSESSIONID=$SESSION_ID" \
                        $base_url/api/flows/$CURRENT_DB/$CURRENT_TABLE \
                        );
                echo "setInputTableForCurrentFlow $CURRENT_DB $CURRENT_TABLE $PARTITION_CONTAINS_EQUAL_SIGN";
                echo $server_response;
        else
                echo $SERVER_NOT_RUNNING;
        fi
fi
}

function getCurrentTable(){
echo "getCurrentTable $CURRENT_DB $CURRENT_TABLE $PARTITION_CONTAINS_EQUAL_SIGN"
if [ -z $CURRENT_DB ] && [ -z $CURRENT_TABLE ] ;
then
        echo "table is not set";
else
        echo $CURRENT_DB.$CURRENT_TABLE;
fi
}
```

I have one another shell script named as `demo.sh` which consumes these two functions like this:

```
INPUT_TABLE=default.clickstream
TABLE_CONTAINS_COLUMN_HEADERS=false
. $SCRIPT_HOME/./functions.sh

setTable=`setInputTableForCurrentFlow $INPUT_TABLE $TABLE_CONTAINS_COLUMN_HEADERS`;
echo "$setTable";
echo $(getCurrentTable);
```

so if I execute the `demo.sh` script like `sh demo.sh`

```
output
setInputTableForCurrentFlow default clickstream false
getCurrentTable table is not set
```

this is not supposed to happen
But here is a little strange thing which i found out. If I change `demo.sh` like this

```
INPUT_TABLE=default.clickstream
TABLE_CONTAINS_COLUMN_HEADERS=false
. $SCRIPT_HOME/./functions.sh

setInputTableForCurrentFlow $INPUT_TABLE $TABLE_CONTAINS_COLUMN_HEADERS;
echo $(getCurrentTable);
```

and the right output is

```
setInputTableForCurrentFlow default clickstream false
getCurrentTable default clickstream false default.clickstream
```

So guys my question is what is difference between calling the same with two different ways ? and If I want to store the output of the function `setInputTableForCurrentFlow` without calling it twice what should i do ?

> any pointers are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first example executes the function in a [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) (`` `...` `` or `$(...)`), which runs in a [subshell environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) and can not modify the parent's environment.  This means that the environment modification made in `setInputTableForCurrentFlow` do not persist to the calling of `getCurrentTable`.  The second example modifies the environment as intended.

A variable like `CURRENT_DB` can be used to store the output of `setInputTableForCurrentFlow`, or a variable specified as an argument `export "$3=$server_response"`.  In some shells `read` can set variable when it is the last member of a pipeline, but that behavior is implementation defined.
`setInputTableForCurrentFlow $INPUT_TABLE $TABLE_CONTAINS_COLUMN_HEADERS | read setTable`

If `setTable` is only needed for a short period `read` can be used to set `setTable` in a subshell.

```
setInputTableForCurrentFlow $INPUT_TABLE $TABLE_CONTAINS_COLUMN_HEADERS | (
        read setTable
        echo $setTable
    )
```

Comment: ok kdhp. Is there any way to execute all my functions like in the first example in the same process ?? I dont wanna modify the functions.sh script

Comment: @sachin Another possibility was added.  If that fails, `zsh` has the `[[` operator, and supports the first usage of `read` shown in the answer.

Comment: setTable is working fine but I want to use variables set by setInputTableForCurrentFlow function in getCurrentTable function without executing the statements like in the second example

Comment: @sachin In order to do that it can not be in a command substitution (`\`...\``), and without a command substitution an alternative method must be used to set `setTable`.  It has to be _like_ in the second example, but it may be able to make it work like in the first.  Beyond that the functions will likely have to be modified.